# Mustache.php debugging

Tags: php, debugging, mustache

I get an error:

```
Warning: htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in ...
```

I know what cause the error but i dont know where. The system has around thousand templates which are processed in one step. So I need to get some more output. First of all Mustache.php creates temporary php files which get executed with eval() function. This makes it a pain to debug. In this special case i can wrap the escape with the start options:

```
$options['escape'] = function($value){
    if(is_array($value)){
        var_dump($value);
        exit();
    }
    return htmlspecialchars($value, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
};
```

Otherwise you could also use the option "cache" and then lookup the specific class. There you can find a bit of context which helps debugging.

I was wondering if there is any cleaner/nicer way to debug templates in mustache.

Comment: I would probably register an error handler and throw an exception from that warning, then catch the exception outside of the render() call.

Comment: that helps for identify the template, that is a step in the right direction ty ;-). Is it possible to get the line or the "command" from where the error occured ?